# The whole page reload when the usestate is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reload

**My goal is to make an element in which by clicking on the arrows you can set the time**[image: like this]

so I used the **useState** hook

```
type Props = {
    placeholder?: string | number,
    time: number,
}

export function PetTimeSet(props: Props) {
    const {placeholder, time} = props
    // const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState('inactive');
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(time)
    
    const getPadTime = (t:number) => t.toString().padStart(2, '0')

    const hours = getPadTime(Math.floor(currentTime / 60))
    // @ts-ignore
    const minutes = getPadTime(currentTime - hours * 60) 

    useEffect(() => {
        if (Math.floor(currentTime / 60) >= 24) {
            setCurrentTime(0)
        }
    }, [currentTime])

    const handleTimeUncrease = () => setCurrentTime(prevTime => prevTime + 5)
    const handleTimeDecrease = () => setCurrentTime(prevTime => prevTime - 5)

    return (
        <div 
            // onChange={() => setToggleClass('active')}
            //tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
            // onClick={() => {setToggleClass('active')}} 
            className={`PetTimeSet `}>
            <span className="PetTimeSet-index">{placeholder}</span>
            <span className="PetTimeSet-choice">
                <button className="time-decrease">
                    <img src={arrow} alt="decrease" onClick={handleTimeDecrease} />
                </button>

                <span className="PetTimeSet-time">{`${hours}:${minutes}`}</span>

                <button className="time-uncrease" onClick={handleTimeUncrease}>
                    <img src={arrow} alt="uncrease" />
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

However, each time you click on the button to increase or decrease the page, **the action is triggered once, then the entire page is reloaded**. I can't understand what could be the reason

I've tried passing functions to the element, I've tried using the useEffect hook differently, I've tried pushing everything to the root element of the page. The result is the same. Page reloads

Comment: Could it be possible that you have wrapped this component inside of a `form`? If yes, you can try giving `type="button"` to both the buttons to fix.

Comment: Yes, this component is inside the forn! I'll try this.. and it works. Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: @DmitrZar If you have solved this problem which is specific to you, perhaps you should delete the question